# jquery validation tooltip on a custom styled file upload button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i have a file upload button which has been styled using css to give the button a better look and added the [bootstrap validation tooltip](https://github.com/Thrilleratplay/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip) to my form.

The problem is when a file is not selected and when we hit the submit button, the validation tooltip is shown inside the button div making it harder to read. How can i make it appear button/div?

```
<form id="theform" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-success">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" name="upload" required/>
</div>

 <div class="row">
 <input class="btn btn-primary pull-left" value="Check 'em" type="submit" style="float:left">
 </div> 

 </form>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#theform").validate({
                rules: {

                    upload: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    upload: "please select file"
                },
                tooltip_options: {

                    upload: {
                        placement: 'top',

                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $("#validity_label").html('<div class="alert alert-success">No errors.  Like a boss.</div>');
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    $("#validity_label").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">There be ' + validator.numberOfInvalids() + ' error' + (validator.numberOfInvalids() > 1 ? 's' : '') + ' here.  </div>');
                }
            });
        });
```

You can check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/pcsmd0cp/2/) which i have created.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The `.validate()` method has **no such option** called `tooltip_options`.  See [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) and [source code](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js).  If this option is mandated by another plugin, then please state such.

Comment: Also, [your jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/pcsmd0cp/) is totally useless... it contains no JavaScript and the jQuery & jQuery plugins are not included.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tooltip plugin.  To solve this, you'll probably have to inspect your rendered DOM and tweak the error placement using the `errorPlacement` option.

Comment: A jsFiddle that is complete:  https://jsfiddle.net/b61wr8j8/

Comment: @Sparky Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/pcsmd0cp/2/